# Use htaccess in a subdirectory to access a specifice file with a php extention

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory

Presently I have htaccess in `domain.com` to access `file.php` - Works great!

```
RewriteOptions inherit    
RewriteEngine on    
Options -Indexes    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$    
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/file\.php" [R=301,L]
```

It looks like this when entered: `www.domain.com/file.php`

Ok, what I'm not able to figure is how to place something similar in a subdirectory.  Example result would be: `www.domain.com/subfolder/file.php`.
The htaccess file cannot reside in `www.domain.com` like the htaccess example above. It (htaccess) has to be in the subdirectory.

I wish I knew how to do this.  I searched the web and tried several different ideas, but my experience with apache and htaccess is limited.

Greatly appreciate any help or direction to existing examples that have already answered my question.